# Are there $f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\times\mathbb R^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{+}$ associative and not conjugate to the addition?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, semigroups, binary-operations, associativity

We say that

> **Definition** A function $f:X\times X\rightarrow X$ is associative if $\forall a,b,c \in X\; f(f(a,b),c)=f(a,f(b,c))$
>
> **Definition** Associative functions $f,g:X\times X\rightarrow X$ with $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are said to be conjugate if there exists a continuous injective function $\varphi: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow 
> \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f\circ (\varphi, \varphi)=\varphi\circ g $

For example the multiplication on the positive reals is conjugate to the sum as $\times \circ (\exp,\exp)=\exp \circ +$.

So a natural question would be:

> Are there continuous $f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\times \mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{+}$ associative and not conjugate to the addition and such that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\; f(x,\cdot), f(\cdot,x)$ are injective?

Note that the last hypothesis was added to exclude trivial cases like the constant functions.

Comment: This is closely related to [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y).$

Comment: I think in general case the answer is no. but in the case of $\Bbb R^+$ seems to be true.

Comment: The logarithm is not bijective, rather it takes positive reals bijectively to all reals. So addition and multiplication and not conjugate as maps $\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: thank you, I edited

Comment: You probably want to also require $f(\cdot, x)$ to be injective; otherwise $f(x,y)=y$ works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your definition of "conjugate" is highly unnatural because it requires $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\varphi:X\to X$.  Note also that by your definition, multiplication on $\mathbb{R}^+$ is not conjugate to addition on $\mathbb{R}$, since you have only defined what it means for two operations on the *same* set to be conjugate.  Moreover, your definition of conjugacy is not symmetric in $f$ and $g$, so it is unclear what it means.  As stated, your definition essentially says that $f$ and $g$ are conjugate if the semigroup defined $g$ embeds in the semigroup defined by $f$.  Taking $g$ to be addition, this would say that the semigroup defined by $f$ contains a copy of the addition semigroup $\mathbb{R}^+$, whereas it seems that what you intend is for $f$ to be contained in the addition semigroup $\mathbb{R}$.

Let me make a better definition which seems to be the meaning you are aiming for.  A *topological semigroup* is a topological space $X$ together with a continuous associative binary operation.  Two topological semigroups are isomorphic if there is a homeomorphism between them which turns the binary operation on one into the binary operation on the other.  I will then say a binary operation on $\mathbb{R}^+$ is conjugate to addition if it is isomorphic as a topological semigroup to $(X,+)$ for some $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ (which is necesssarily an open interval).

Note in particular that there are three different isomorphism types of such topological semigroups $(X,+)$ where $X$ is an open interval: we could have $X=\mathbb{R}$, $X=\mathbb{R}^+$ (or equivalently $\mathbb{R}^-$), or $X=(a,\infty)$ for $a>0$ (or equivalently, $(-\infty,a)$ for $a<0$).  These are not isomorphic since the first is a group, the second is not a group but $+$ is surjective, and in the third $+$ is not even surjective.  And all of these are possible isomorphism types of topological semigroup structures on $\mathbb{R}^+$, since we can just pick a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to each of these intervals and transport addition along the homeomorphism.

Now here's the interesting conclusion: every continuous associative binary operation on $\mathbb{R}^+$ which is injective in each variable is conjugate to addition in this sense.  That is, every cancellative topological semigroup structure on $\mathbb{R}^+$ is isomorphic to one of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}^+$, or $(1,\infty)$ with addition.

---

Here's a proof.  Since $\mathbb{R}^+$ is homeomorphic to $I=(0,1)$, I will work with $I$ instead.  I will often write our binary operation $f$ as multiplication, so for instance $f(x,y)=xy$ (I will never use ordinary multiplication of elements of $I$).

Note first that since $f(x,\cdot)$ is injective, it is either increasing or decreasing.  The set of $x$ such that $f(x,\cdot)$ is increasing is open by continuity, as is the set of $x$ such that $f(x,\cdot)$ is decreasing, so by connectedness $f(x,\cdot)$ is either increasing for all $x$ or decreasing for all $x$.  But note that if we compose $f(x,\cdot)$ and $f(y,\cdot)$ we get $f(xy,\cdot)$ by associativity, and so $f(xy,\cdot)$ is always increasing.  We conclude that actually $f(x,\cdot)$ is always increasing, and similarly $f(\cdot,x)$ is increasing.

Now fix some element $a\in I$.  Let us first assume that $a^2>a$.  Then since multiplication is increasing we get $a<a^2<a^3<\dots$.  Let $R=\lim a^n$.  If $R<1$, observe that $R^2=R$ by continuity, but also $aR=R$ by continuity, which is a contradiction since $a<R$.  Thus $R=1$.

Now let's interpolate between the powers of $a$.  For any $q=\frac{m}{n}$ where $m\geq n\geq 1$ are integers, note that by the intermediate value theorem there is $x\geq a$ such that $x^n=a^m$ (specifically, there is such an $x$ between $a^{\lfloor q\rfloor}$ and $a^{\lfloor q\rfloor+1}$).  This $x$ is moreover unique since $x\mapsto x^n$ is strictly increasing.  Define $a^q$ to be this unique $x$ (which, by uniqueness, does not depend on the denominator $n$ chosen for $q$).  Note moreover that if $xy<yx$ then $x^2y^2<xyxy<yx^2y<yxyx<y^2x^2$, and similarly $x^ny^n<y^nx^n$ for all integers $n\geq 1$.  Contrapositively, then, if $x^n$ and $y^n$ commute for some $n$, then $x$ and $y$ must also commute.  We conclude that all the numbers of the form $a^q$ commute, and then it follows easily that $a\mapsto a^q$ is a strictly increasing semigroup homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}\cap[1,\infty)\to [a,1)$.  For any $r\in[1,\infty)$, define $a^{r^-}=\sup\{a^q:q\leq r\}$ and $a^{r^+}=\inf\{a^q:q>r\}$.  Say that $r$ is bad if $a^{r^-}\neq a^{r^+}$.

Note now that there can be only countably many bad $r$, since the open intervals $(a^{r^-},a^{r^+})$ are disjoint for distinct bad $r$.  Moreover, if $s$ is good and $r$ is bad, then $r+s$ is also bad, since $a^{(r+s)^-}=a^{r^-}a^{s^-}$ and $a^{(r+s)^+}=a^{r^+}a^{s^+}$.  But since there must be uncountably many good $s$, this means that if there is any bad $r$, there would be uncountably many bad $r$.  Thus there are no bad $r$; that is, $a^{r^-}=a^{r^+}$ for all $r\in[1,\infty)$.

We can now define $a^r=a^{r^-}=a^{r^+}$ for each $r\in[1,\infty)$ and it is clear that $g(r)=a^r$ is a continuous strictly increasing map $g:[1,\infty)\to [a,1)$.  By continuity, the image of $g$ is connected, and thus is all of $[a,1)$, so $g$ is a bijection.  Since $g$ is a semigroup homomorphism on the rationals, it is a semigroup homomorphism everywhere by continuity.

We have thus shown that if $a^2>a$, then there is a unique increasing semigroup isomorphism $L_a:[a,1)\to[1,\infty)$ (the "base $a$ logarithm").  In particular, for any $b>a$, we also have $b^2>b$, and by uniqueness, $L_b(x)=L_a(x)/L_a(b)$ for all $x\in [b,1)$.  Let $c=\inf\{a\in I:a^2>a\}$.  Fixing some $a>c$, we can then extend $L_a$ to all of $(c,1)$ by defining $L_a(b)=L_a(x)/L_b(x)$ for any $x>\max(a,b)$.  Letting $r=\inf\{1/L_a(b):b>c\}$, then this definition makes $L_a$ an increasing semigroup isomorphism $h_+:(c,1)\to(r,\infty)$.  (Note that $\{a\in I:a^2>a\}$ may be empty in which case we just say $c=1$ and $r=\infty$ and all of this is vacuous.)

Similarly, letting $d=\sup\{a\in I:a^2<a\}$, we can define an increasing semigroup isomorphism $h_-:(0,d)\to (-\infty,s)$ for some $s<0$ (again this may be vacuous with $d=0$ and $s=-\infty$).  If either $c=0$ or $d=1$ we are now done, since either $h_+$ or $h_-$ is defined on all of $I$.  So, we assume $c>0$ and $d<1$.  In that case, by continuity we can extend $h_+$ to $[c,1)\to [r,\infty)$ and $h_-$ to $(0,d]\to(-\infty,s]$ and they remain homomorphisms.

If $c=d$, we see we must have $r=s=0$ (since we must have $c^2\geq c$ and $d^2\leq d$ by continuity), and the element $c$ is an identity element for our multiplication.  Now note that $f^{-1}(I\setminus\{c\})\subset I^2$ is disconnected, separated into $f^{-1}(0,c)$ and $f^{-1}(c,1)$.  It follows that $f^{-1}(\{c\})$ must have more than one point and in fact must contain points of both $(c,1)\times(0,c)$ and $(0,c)\times(c,1)$.  So there is $a>c$ and $b<c$ such that $ab=c$.  For any $a'$ with $c<a'<a$, by continuity $a'$ must have a right inverse between $b$ and $c$.  But we also have $a^nb^n=c$ for any $n$, and since every element of $(c,1)$ is less than some power of $a$, we conclude every $a>c$ has a right inverse.  Similarly every $a>c$ has a left inverse, and every $b<c$ has a left and right inverse.  Thus every element of $I$ has an inverse on each side, which implies every element of $I$ has a two-sided inverse.

That is, the elements less than $c$ are just the inverses of the elements greater than $c$.  We can thus extend $h_+$ to an increasing isomorphism $I\to \mathbb{R}$ by defining $h_+(b)=-h_+(b^{-1})$ for $b<c$, and thus we have an isomorphism of topological semigroups from $I$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with addition.

The one remaining case is that $c\neq d$, in which case we must have $c>d$.  We then have $e^2=e$ for all $e\in [d,c]$.  In particular, $cd<c^2=c$ but $(cd)d=cd^2=cd$, which is a contradiction since right multiplication by $d$ is strictly increasing.  So this last case is impossible.

Comment: Thank you a lot, that's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 4):

Consider the function $$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{f : \Bbb R^+ \times \Bbb R^+ \to \Bbb R^+, \qquad f(x, y) := x + y + 1}} .$$

> It is straightforward to verify that $f$ is associative and that the functions $x \mapsto f(x, a)$ and $y \mapsto f(a, y)$ are injective for all $a$ (they are increasing). Suppose $f$ is conjugate to addition via the (continuous, injective) function $\varphi$, that is, that $$\phantom{(\ast)} \qquad \boxed{\varphi(x) + \varphi(y) + 1 = \varphi(x + y)} . \qquad (\ast)$$ Since $\varphi$ is continuous and injective, it is strictly monotone, and $(\ast)$ forces $\varphi$ to be increasing. Thus, as $x \searrow 0$, $\varphi(x)$ decreases and is bounded below (by $0$), so $\lim_{x \searrow 0} \varphi(x)$ exists, and we can extend $\varphi$ uniquely to a continuous function $\tilde\varphi: \tilde X \to \tilde X$, $\tilde X := [0, \infty)$. We can likewise extend $f$ to a (continuous) function $\tilde f : \tilde X \times \tilde X \to \tilde X$ defined by the same rule as $f$, and by continuity $(\ast)$ still holds if we replace $\varphi$ with $\tilde \varphi$ therein. Taking $y = 0$ and canceling leaves $1 + \tilde \varphi(0) = 0$, which contradicts that $\tilde\varphi$ only takes on nonnegative values. So, $f$ is not conjugate to addition.

Comment: Note that this assumes "$f$ is conjugate to addition" means that $f$ plays the role of $f$ and addition plays the role of $g$ in the definition of conjugation.  If you swap the roles, then $f$ _is_ conjugate to addition, by $\varphi(x)=x^2+1$.  This asymmetry is due to some rather unfortunate choices in OP's definition of "conjugate"; see my answer for a more sensible definition and a more satisfying answer for that definition.

Comment: In that sense, "$f$ is conjugate to $g$" as described by OP isn't even well-defined, since OP only defines "$f, g$ are conjugate if...", and like you say the $f$ in my answer is only a counterexample if the definition is interpreted in the "forward" direction. I must admit, I didn't notice the asymmetry of the definition myself until you pointed it out. (Also NB that OP edited the question to change the domain/codomain of $\varphi$ sometime after I first opened the page. To satisfy the current definition, $\varphi$ should be extended arbitrarily to a function continuous on all of $\Bbb R$.)

Comment: (And +1 to your excellent answer, BTW, which answers the question OP presumably wanted to ask.)

Comment: Note that a simpler variant on your answer is just $f(x,y)=1+x+y$.  The point is that you're making an operation which is isomorphic to addition on $(1,\infty)$, which does not contain a copy of addition on $(0,\infty)$ (which OP's definition, interpreted in the direction you did, says).

Comment: You're right---I hope you don't mind that I've replaced the example with the variant you give here, since it simplifies the exposition. Thanks for your insightful comments!